# Delete the array items which have lower specific value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to let array1 transform to array2.
The keyword is the test,test2,885,length.I want the keyword's next value(#?) to the next # is the highest.

```
var array1=["4#test#4#T#limited","6#test#6#885#restricted","7#test2#2#2#limited","8#test2#4#3#limited","11#885#1#TT#restricted","15#length#1#taw#restricted","17#885#11#T#limited"];

var arrar2=["6#test#6#885#restricted","8#test2#4#3#limited","17#885#11#T#limited","15#length#1#taw#restricted"];
```

Comment: You condition on splitting is not clear.  Can you add more details to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
var array1=["4#test#4#T#limited","6#test#6#885#restricted","7#test2#2#2#limited","8#test2#4#3#limited","11#885#1#TT#restricted","15#length#1#taw#restricted","17#885#11#T#limited"];
var keywords = ["test","test2","885","length"];
var array2 = [];
keywords.forEach(function (key) {
    var matched = [];
    var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + key + "#(\\d+)");
    array1.forEach(function (value) {
        if (regex.test(value)) {
            matched.push([parseInt(RegExp.$1), value]);
        }
    });
    if (matched.length > 0) {
        matched.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b[0] - a[0];
        });
        array2.push(matched[0][1]);
    }
});
alert(array2);
```

<kbd>[**JsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ArieShout/4RGed/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use underscorejs to filter.

http://underscorejs.org/#filter

Then you can use javascript Array's **sort** method to sort the array if needed. You can pass a custom sorting function to sort. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to "delete items from an array" based on the items fulfilling a condition is to use `Array.prototype.filter` (with the condition reversed).

In your case, it's rather hard to do because of how you organized your data (bundling it all in a string makes it hard to work with). Here is how i would work around it, but feel free to structure your data better from the start to avoid the awkward conversions:

```
var array1=["4#test#4#T#limited","6#test#6#885#restricted","7#test2#2#2#limited","8#test2#4#3#limited","11#885#1#TT#restricted","15#length#1#taw#restricted","17#885#11#T#limited"];
```

Make the data easier to work with by extracting the keyword and the value (i also keep some information to return to the original shape of the array):

```
var saneData = array1.map(function(item, index){
  var split = item.split('#');
  return {
    keyword : split[1],
    value: +split[0],
    original : item,
    originalIndex : index
  }
});
```

Sort the data by the keyword (so all items with the same keywords go next to each other) and by the values (so the biggest value is first in a subset with the same keywords):

```
saneData.sort(function(a,b){
  if (a.keyword !== b.keyword) {
    return a.keyword.localeCompare(b.keyword);
  } else {
    return b.value - a.value;
  }
});
```

Filter the array, keeping just the first item in a subset with the same keyword:

```
var filteredData = saneData.filter(function(item, index) {
  if (index === 0) return true; // first item is good
  return item.keyword !== saneData[index-1].keyword;
});
```

Return to the original form of the array (with the order preserved):

```
var array2 = filteredData.sort(function(a,b){ return a.originalIndex - b.originalIndex; }).map(function(item){ return item.original; });

// Result: ["6#test#6#885#restricted", "8#test2#4#3#limited", "15#length#1#taw#restricted", "17#885#11#T#limited"]
```